# Regex Search in Python: Exclude port 22 lines with ' line 22 '

Tags: python, regex

My current regex search in python looks for lines with `' 22 '`, but I would like to exclude lines that have `' line 22 '`. How could I express this in `Regex`? Would I be `'.*(^line) 22 .*$'`

```
import re

sshRegexString='.* 22 .*$'
sshRegexExpression=re.compile(sshRegexString)
```

Comment: What is your final code ? What is the output ? What is the problem ?

Comment: `.*(?<!line) 22 .*$`

Comment: @revo That regex worked! Thanks

Comment: @revo It matches `exa line 22 mole 22 erer`

Comment: Well if it is a port number it shouldn't exist multiple times. @Kasramvd

Comment: @revo It's clear that what's the output format.

Comment: What is output format? @Kasramvd

Comment: @revo I meant output of socket or etc, but it's better to say the input text format. Wea are not if there are concatenated lines together or not. or If we only have one port number in each line.

Comment: @pHorseSpec: Are you reading file line by line? If yes, you do not even need a regex: just check if `"line 22 "` is not in `line` and `" 22 "` is in it.

Answer (score 0):

You current requirement to find a line that *contains*  `22`  but does not contain `line 22`  can  be implemented without the help of a regex.

Just check if these texts are `in` or are `not in` the string inside list comprehension. Here is a [Python demo](http://ideone.com/o2jFU7) (I assume you have lines in a list, but it can be adjusted to handling lines read from file one by one):

```
lines = ['Some text 1 line 22 here', 'Some text 2 Text2 22 here', 'Some text 3 Text3 22 here']
good = [s for s in lines if ' 22 ' in s and 'line 22 ' not in s]
print(good) # the first lines[0] is not printed!
```